# Why is my SQL query not returning any records when it should be?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a select query with a bunch of where clauses. I tested a couple situations and they worked great! BUT tested another situation and it didn't return anything when it should have.

In access, i used the "create query" feature, I put all the same values and it returned 4 records, which is what it is expected! So, why is my query not able to find these records?

```
Set rstV = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tableVName & " WHERE ValveSize IN (" & mVSize & "," & mLineSize & ") AND ValveFamily = '" & confgType & _
    "' AND CV >= " & mCV & " AND NO = 'X'")
```

when I remove NO = 'X' , then it finds a bunch of records (including the ones that I am looking for), but I need NO='X' so that I can specifically find those 4 records.

i have a feeling that 'X' might be causing the issue some how, but it worked in other situations. I tried looking at columns field properties and it all looks good...

please help!

Comment: Have you made a simplified version of this query? `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE No='X'` to confirm there are no issues with your suspected problem causing criteria? Your query has a lot of variables, and we can't see a sample of your data so its hard to tell what might be causing it.

Comment: Hi @ChanceFinley yes I tried it and effectively it does not return anything... which is why i checked field properties for that specific table and everything is the same as the other 2 tables.

Comment: Also, the NO column either has a blank record or an X, but again why did it work for the other tables and not this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is far as I recall, YES and NO could be values, so try using brackets around NO:

```
[NO] = 'X'
```

Comment: @Ants This is likely the problem. MS Access could use these as protected words, considering Access's True/False, is actually a 1 or 0/yes or no